# How to append to error column when using the Macro Design (before change) inside of MS Access?

Tags: excel, vba, database, ms-access

I have an MS Access database that receives hundreds of row records coming into it. I need a way to validate that the incoming data is consistent with the business logic. For example, when we get a record the state column should be "California", otherwise an error should be appended to an Error column that specifies why it failed. And for that same record if the Income is less than $1,000,000 an error should be appended for that too.

I found that inside MS Access while highlighting your table if you at the top bar click on Table > Before Change, you can create If-then logic for incoming rows. If there is a better way to accomplish this task, please let me know.

Once I am inside the "Before change" window I then write this logic out:

```
If [State] <> "California" Then
    SetField
    Name Error
    Value = "Failed on incorrect state"

Else if [Income] < 1000000 Then
    SetField
    Name Error
    Value = "Failed on incorrect income"
End if
```

When multiple errors occur such as both incorrect state and income it only shows the first error. Is there a way to have both errors appended to the same error column?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use AND statement in the IF section.

```
If [STATE] <> "California" && [INCOME] < 10000000 Then 
//Write your logic here. Such as "Incorrect Value".
```

Hope it works for you.